# Excel Formula calculating the starting date of a given calendar week

Tags: excel, date, formula

Given a table with the following entries:

```
     A                B       C             D
1
2
3    Calendar Week    Year    Start Date    End Date
4    5                2022    31/01/2022    06/02/200
```

I would like to compute the Start and End Date of the week based on the Calendar Week. I have found a suitable formula with a quick Google Search:

Start Date = `DATE(B4;1;7*A4-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;;-1))-2)`

I don't really understand this formula though.

Apparently it calculates a date, given the year (B4), the first month of the year (January) and the number of days that have passed since 01.01. based on the calendar week. The number of days are equal to 7*CW - some Math. I don't understand the Math: I am calculating a weekday (1 to 7) based on the day that the previous year ended on (2021 ends on a Friday = 5) and then I substract 2. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of the weekday and subtracting a constant is supposed to be adjusting the number of days to consider on what day the calendar week starts.

In 2022, depending on whether your weeks start on Sunday (typical in the US) or Monday (typical in Europe), the first calendar week starts on Sunday Jan. 2 or Monday, Jan 3.

There are various definitions of the "calendar week", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date. The ISO definition (citing from there):

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the first Thursday of the Gregorian year (i.e. of January) in it. The following definitions based on properties of this week are mutually equivalent, since the ISO week starts with Monday:
>
> - It is the first week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in
>   January.
> - Its first day is the Monday nearest to 1 January.
> - It has 4 January in it. Hence the earliest possible first week extends from
>   Monday 29 December (previous Gregorian year) to Sunday 4 January, the
>   latest possible first week extends from Monday 4 January to Sunday 10
>   January.
> - It has the year's first working day in it, if Saturdays,
>   Sundays and 1 January are not working days.

So I first propose this formula:

```
=DATE(B4;1;7*(A4-1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))+5)
```

This formula is determining the first day of the first week in the year, then adding 7 times the calendar week to it to determine the start of later calendar weeks.

What we need for the outer `DATE(B4;1;7*(A4-1)...)` in the formula for the day parameter is to compute the day of January that is the Sunday of the first week. (i.e. start of the week in US convention). That is the Sunday on or before January 4th.

`WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))` returns the weekday of Jan. 4th. For example for B4 = 2022, this is a Tuesday and the function returns 3.

To get the day in January of Sunday in that week, we need to subtract that weekday value from 5.

Reasoning: If Jan 4 is itself a Sunday, its `WEEKDAY` is 1; subtracting this from 5 leads to the desired result, 4. (For the 4th of January). For each day later in the week that Jan 4 occurs, we need to subtract one more from 5 to get the date of the Sunday. So in general, `-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))+5` will be the day of January on which the Sunday of the first week falls. (If it is negative, it will be a day in December)

Example: If Jan 4 is a Tuesday, as in 2022, its `WEEKDAY` is 3 and we need to subtract it from 5 to get 2 for Jan 2.

Now we add 7 days per week times the calendar week `7*(A4-1)`, but subtracting 1 since the calendar week is basically a 1-based index and we need the offset here.

Having confirmed the first formula, we note that by using the distributive principle

`7*(A4-1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))+5`
is the same as
`7*A4-7-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))+5`
is the same as
`7*A4-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))-2`

So the final formula is

```
=DATE(B4;1;7*A4-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4))-2)
```

So for A4 = 1, in year 2022 we get Jan. 2 itself. For 2023 we would get Jan. 1, the first Sunday of 2023.

**Edit:**

Depending on the exact definition of the start of the week and first week of the year, the formula needs to be adjusted. The above was really a mixture of the ISO-8601 definition of the first week "contains Jan. 4", but having the week start on Sunday, not Monday as in ISO-8601.

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Numbering the following is given as definition of the first week according to various conventions:

| System | First day of week | First week.. | of year | ...contains | Can be last week of previous year | Used by or in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ISO-8601 | Monday | 4 January | 1st Thursday | 4–7 days of year | yes | EU (exc. Portugal) and most of other European countries, most of Asia and Oceania |
| (Middle Eastern) | Saturday | 1 January | 1st Friday | 1–7 days of year | yes | Much of the Middle East |
| (Western traditional) | Sunday | 1 January | 1st Saturday | 1–7 days of year | yes | Canada, United States, Iceland, Portugal, Japan, Taiwan, Thailand, Hong Kong, Macau, Israel, Egypt, South Africa, the Philippines, and most of Latin America |

To be more exact the following formulas are also proposed:

**ISO-8601**

Here, the WEEKDAY function is given its second optional parameter = 2 to indicate that Monday should be the first day of the week (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.weekday )

```
=DATE(B4;1;7*A4-WEEKDAY(DATE(B4;1;4);2)-2)
```

**Middle Eastern**

Here, Saturday is the first day of the week and (parameter 16) and we adjust by subtracting 5 to bring Jan. 1 into the first week:

```
=DATE(B17;1;7*C17-WEEKDAY(DATE(B17;1;1);16)-5)
```

**Western traditional**

Here, Sunday is the first day of the week and (parameter 1) and we adjust by subtracting 5 to bring Jan. 1 into the first week:

```
=DATE(B17;1;7*C17-WEEKDAY(DATE(B17;1;1);1)-5)
```

These are the results for the start of the first week for the next few years:

| Year | Week | ISO-8601 | Middle East | Western traditional |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | Monday, 03 Jan 2022 | Saturday, 01 Jan 2022 | Sunday, 26 Dec 2021 |
| 2023 | 1 | Monday, 02 Jan 2023 | Saturday, 31 Dec 2022 | Sunday, 01 Jan 2023 |
| 2024 | 1 | Monday, 01 Jan 2024 | Saturday, 30 Dec 2023 | Sunday, 31 Dec 2023 |
| 2025 | 1 | Monday, 30 Dec 2024 | Saturday, 28 Dec 2024 | Sunday, 29 Dec 2024 |
| 2026 | 1 | Monday, 29 Dec 2025 | Saturday, 27 Dec 2025 | Sunday, 28 Dec 2025 |
| 2027 | 1 | Monday, 04 Jan 2027 | Saturday, 26 Dec 2026 | Sunday, 27 Dec 2026 |
| 2028 | 1 | Monday, 03 Jan 2028 | Saturday, 01 Jan 2028 | Sunday, 26 Dec 2027 |
| 2029 | 1 | Monday, 01 Jan 2029 | Saturday, 30 Dec 2028 | Sunday, 31 Dec 2028 |
| 2030 | 1 | Monday, 31 Dec 2029 | Saturday, 29 Dec 2029 | Sunday, 30 Dec 2029 |
| 2031 | 1 | Monday, 30 Dec 2030 | Saturday, 28 Dec 2030 | Sunday, 29 Dec 2030 |
| 2032 | 1 | Monday, 29 Dec 2031 | Saturday, 27 Dec 2031 | Sunday, 28 Dec 2031 |
| 2033 | 1 | Monday, 03 Jan 2033 | Saturday, 01 Jan 2033 | Sunday, 26 Dec 2032 |
| 2034 | 1 | Monday, 02 Jan 2034 | Saturday, 31 Dec 2033 | Sunday, 01 Jan 2034 |
| 2035 | 1 | Monday, 01 Jan 2035 | Saturday, 30 Dec 2034 | Sunday, 31 Dec 2034 |
| 2036 | 1 | Monday, 31 Dec 2035 | Saturday, 29 Dec 2035 | Sunday, 30 Dec 2035 |
| 2037 | 1 | Monday, 29 Dec 2036 | Saturday, 27 Dec 2036 | Sunday, 28 Dec 2036 |
| 2038 | 1 | Monday, 04 Jan 2038 | Saturday, 26 Dec 2037 | Sunday, 27 Dec 2037 |